# Show that the limit exists and find it's value?

Tags: limits, fibonacci-numbers, recursive-algorithms

The Fibonacci series defined recursively by $x(1) = 1, x(2) = 2$ and 
$x(n+1) = x(n) + x(n-1)$

Find$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x(n+1)}{x(n)}$$

Comment: There's a nice explicit formula for the $n$th term of the Fibonacci sequence. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $L= \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{x(n+1)}{x(n)}= L$. By the recursive definition we also have that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{x(n+1)}{x(n)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{x(n)+x(n-1)}{x(n)}= 1+\dfrac{1}{L}$. Therefore,

$$\begin{align*}1+\dfrac{1}{L}=L\\
L^2 - L - 1=0
\end{align*}$$

So $$\dfrac{L=1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$.

Comment: Thanks Orangutango. I was stuck at 1 + (1/L) but your solution did the rest.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If we denote $\lambda = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x(n+1)}{x(n)} \neq 0$ then

$$\lambda = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x(n)+x(n-1)}{x(n)} = 1+\frac{1}{\lambda}.$$

Also, observe that $x(n) < x(n+1) < 2x(n)$, which gives you convergence (see the [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)) and $1 < \lambda < 2$.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: I came up to this. But can't proceed further. Anyway i got the solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Shravan40 Don't forget about the convergence (as I did, fixed now).

Answer (score 1):

$\cfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\cfrac{x_n+x_{n-1}}{x_n}=1+\cfrac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}$

Now take $l=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\cfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$

$l=1+\cfrac{1}{l}$

Comment: I came up to this. But can't proceed further. Anyway i got the solution. Thanks for your help.